# function contains over XML using Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xpath

I have a table 'MYTABLE' with column XML_COL of type XMLTYPE.
I am trying to execute a xpath query to retrieve the numer of element that have text like '00'

The xml stored in the column is:

```
<ROOT>
  <DOCUMENT myattribute="001">
   <NODE>a</NODE>
  </DOCUMENT>
  <DOCUMENT myattribute="002">
   <NODE>b</NODE>
  </DOCUMENT>
<ROOT>
```

I know that I search for attribute value in this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE
WHERE existsNode(XML_COL,'/DOCUMENT[@myattribute = ''001'']') = 1;
```

Is it possible to execute a like or contains over attribute value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it as an XMLTABLE instead, perhaps?

```
with mytable as (select xmltype('<ROOT>
  <DOCUMENT myattribute="001">
   <NODE>a</NODE>
  </DOCUMENT>
  <DOCUMENT myattribute="002">
   <NODE>b</NODE>
  </DOCUMENT>
  <DOCUMENT myattribute="013">
   <NODE>c</NODE>
  </DOCUMENT>
</ROOT>') xml_col from dual)
select count(*) 
from   mytable mt,
       xmltable('//ROOT/DOCUMENT' passing mt.xml_col
                columns doc_attribute varchar2(5) path '@myattribute',
                        node varchar2(10) path 'NODE') x
where  x.doc_attribute like '00%';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         2
```